# Pass event to directive and subscribe to it

Tags: angular, angular5, observable, angular2-directives, eventemitter

I have a directive which has an Output of EventEmitter.
I would like to do something when the subscription of the emitted event returned subscription is completed.

(for example, I would like to do console.log('test') when save() of example.component is completed. - I am aware I can do that in the example.component's save method but I am doing something generic so I need it in the directive).

```
import { Directive, OnInit, HostListener, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSingleActiveButton]'
})
export class SingleActiveButtonDirective {
  @Output() appSingleActiveButton: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  private onClick(e: any): void {
    this.appSingleActiveButton.next(e);
    //determine somehow that the referred function's subscription is completed and do something
    // for example what I tried is: this.appSingleActiveButton.subscribe(() => console.log('do some other stuff'))
  }
}
```

and I have a component which has an element with that directive and pass a function which returns Subscription.

example.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss'],
})
export class ExampleComponent {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public save(index: number): Subscription {
    const requestUrl = 'http://example.com';
    return this.http
    .get(requestUrl)
    .map((response) => response.json()).subscribe(() => console.log(`doing some stuff ${index}`));
  }
}
```

example.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of btns; let i = index">
    <div (appSingleActiveButton)="save(i)">test directive</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:
The question is as follows:

How can I determine that the `save()` is completed (either success or error) inside the directive where I actually call it `this.appSingleActiveButton.next(e);`

Comment: What is the question? Is something not working with your solution?

Comment: The questions is as follow, and I will edit the post above:
How can I determine that the save() is completed (either success or error) in the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my previous answer and your explanation, I got your issue right this time.

For your solution, you have several ways of doing what you want.

1. **Given the directive only makes the same thing (HTTP calls)**

For that, you can simply pass the URL as a parameter to your directive, and let the direcdtive handle the HTTP call. You can use an `@Output` to retrive the subscription and subscribe to it in your component.

2. **Given that they do slightly similar things and want to keep the logic into your component**

You can pass your function `save` directly as an `@Input` to your directive. On click, you can run this function, and again, use an `@Output` to get the subscription.

You can also directly take the reference to your element in the constructor, and on click, call the function of that element.

Those are the solutions you can implement. If you need help on the code, feel free to ask for it, but I don't give it to you like that because I'm not your code monkey, and trying is the best way to learn.

Comment: The first solution is not good because I am not doing only http requests (which also has different variables except for the url), I am also doing different thing on success / error for these requests, on top of what I am doing for each request I want to add one more thing which is why I am using a directive.
about the second solution - I already tried that and it worked good, until I had to pass params.
`const parentComponent = (this.viewContainerRef.injector as any).view.component;
    this.appSingleActiveButton.call(parentComponent, e).add(() => this.onRequestResponse());`

Comment: Then pass the parameters as an array to your directive, so that it knows about them. And I wasn't talking about the injector, that's heavy processing, you should rely on `elementRef` instead.

Comment: yea, I was thinking about passing them, will look into that, thanks!